# How to empty a component property in Angular while preserving its type definition?

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, types, undefined

Let's say a component has the following properties:

```
private foo$: Observable<Array<SomeType>>;
private bar: SomeOtherType;
```

---

Later on they get values...

```
this.foo$ = someSubject.pipe(switchMap(...whatever...
this.bar = new SomeOtherType(...whatever...
```

At some point I'd like to empty these two properties for whatever reason, and by emptying I mean remove their values, so set them back to the state they were before they got values.

Making them `undefined` is not an option. If I do that they lose their "type information". I want TypeScript and Angular to know that they are still dealing with an Observable and an object of SomeOtherType.

What options do I have?

Comment: What is "the state they were before they got values", if not `undefined`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan this is what confuses me too. Because once I set `foo$` `undefined` Angular stops considering it as an Observable and even if new values are pushed into its stream again, its subscriptions won't work anymore.

Comment: Take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nykjye). The `obs` variable is set to `undefined` after 5 seconds, and the Observable keeps working.

Comment: Angular has [a tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-search-to-the-dashboard) which is relevant here. It has a [live example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt6/stackblitz.html). In _hero-search.component.ts_ look for the method `search(term: string)`. Add the following code in its body: `if(term == 'undef') this.heroes$ = undefined;`. Type "undef" in the search box. After that the search function stops working.

Comment: The view uses this loop to show the results: `<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes$ | async" >`. The Observable probably stops because the `async` pipe does not have any Observable to subscribe to when `heroes$` is `undefined`. The `async` pipe [unsubscribes automatically](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#description) when the component is destroyed, maybe also when the observable variable becomes `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate this. It's good news that this fault is not because the variable "loses its type" when set to `undefined` as I thought. And for my question the answer is then, just set them to `undefined`, right? Maybe you can post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I would say: you can set them to `undefined` if you don't use the Observables with the `async` pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "set the variables back to the state they were before they got values", set them to `undefined`:

```
this.foo$ = undefined;
this.bar = undefined;
```

In [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xvoojjdxqao) that you took for your tests, the Observable `heroes$` is used with the `async` pipe:

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes$ | async" >
```

If `heroes$` is then set to `undefined`, the list disappears from the view and the Observable stops working. The `async` pipe [unsubscribes automatically](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#description) when the component is destroyed; it appears to do the same when the Observable variable becomes `undefined`.

Except for the case where the Observable is used with the `async` pipe, setting the variable to `undefined` does not stop the Observable from working, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nykjye).

Comment: I think I've found the reason why the observable stops working and I think it's not the async pipe but the code inside the `ngOnInit()` of `HeroSearchComponent`. Setting the observable `undefined` breaks that association between it and the subject. But if you call that piece of code again, it starts working again. I think this is what we overlooked. What do you think? ...Anyways, it's all not that important anymore. My original doubt with `undefined` is cleared.

Comment: That code in `ngOnInit` is the same variable assignment that we discussed from the start. [This modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dx2fye) shows what happens without the `async` pipe. The subscription is done manually in `ngOnInit`. You can see in the console and in the view ouptut that the Observable keeps working after `heroes$` has been set to `undefined` (by typing `undef` in the input field).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can set the type to any rather than undefined.

So for example,
private foo$: Observable>;
private bar: SomeOtherType;